# CLI to put data into AWS Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis-firehose

AWS Firehose was released today. I'm playing around with it and trying to figure out how to put data into the stream using AWS CLI. I have a simple JSON payload and the corresponding Redshift table with columns that map to the JSON attributes. I've tried various combinations but I can't seem to pass in the JSON payload via the cli.

What I've tried:

```
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record '{ "attribute": 1 }'

aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record { "attribute": 1 }

aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record Data='{ "attribute": 1 }'

aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record Data={ "attribute": 1 }

aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --cli-input-json '{ "attribute": 1 }'

aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --cli-input-json { "attribute": 1 }
```

I've looked at the cli help which hasn't helped. [This article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-kinesis-firehose-simple-highly-scalable-data-ingestion/) was published today but looks like the command they use is already outdated as the argument "--firehose-name" has been replaced by "--delivery-stream-name".

Answer (score 8):

Escape the double-quotes around keys and values inside the blob:

```
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record '{"Data":"{\"attribute\":1}"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I have issues with my credentials and region, but this syntax at least got me past parsing errors:

`aws firehose put-record --cli-input-json '{"DeliveryStreamName":"testdata","Record":{"Data":"test data"}}'`

Comment: FYI: Got region straightened out and SUCCESS!

Comment: Sorry, I finally realized I'm just sending a string as data and not a json representation as you're attempting.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.
Escape all quotes.replace *strem_name* with your stream name.

```
aws firehose put-record --cli-input-json "{\"DeliveryStreamName\":\"strem_name\",\"Record\":{\"Data\":\"test data\"}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have tried and it has worked.

Below is the example for sending JSON records with Single Column and multiple columns.

**Single Value in the Data:**

Example: Sending a single column which is an integer.

```
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record='Data="{\"attribute\":1}"'
```

**Multiple column values in the data :**

Example: Sending Integer and String values via Put-record

```
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record='Data="{\"attribute_0\":1,\"attribute_1\":\"Sample String Value\"}"'
```

Example: Sending Integer,String and float values via Put-record

```
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test-delivery-stream --record='Data="{\"attribute_0\":1,\"attribute_1\":\"Sample String Value\",\"attribute_2\":\"14.9\"}"'
```

**Acknowledgement of Success :**

When the record is sent successfully, kinesis acknowledges it with a record id , which is similar to the one below.

```
{
"RecordId": "fFKN2aJfUh6O8FsvlrfkowDZCpu0sx+37JWKJBRmN++iKTYbm/yMKE4dQHdubMR4i+0lDP/NF3c+4y1pvY9gOBkqIn6cfp+1DrB9YG4a0jXmopvhjrXrqYpwo+s8I41kRDKTL013c65vRh5kse238PC7jQ2iOWIqf21wq4dPU9R5qUbicH76soa+bZLvyhGVPudNNu2zRyZwCCV0zP/goah54d/HN9trz"
```

}

This indicates that the put-record command has succeeded.

**Streamed Record on S3:**

This is how the record the record looks like in S3 after kinesis has processed it into S3.

```
{"attribute":1}
{"attribute_0":1,"attribute_1":"Sample String Value"}
{"attribute_0":1,"attribute_1":"Sample String Value","attribute_2":"14.9"}
```

Note : In S3, the records are created in single or multiple files depending on the rate in which we issue the put-record command.

Please do try and comment if this works.

Thanks & Regards,
Srivignesh KN

Answer (score 0):

couple of things:

- did you create the delivery stream?
- by reading the doc it seems that you should do --cli-input-json '{"Data":"blob"}' or --record 'Data=blob'
- try using --generate-cli-skeleton on the cli for the put-record/firehose to see an example

Comment: One thing you could try is putting your ``{"attribute": 1}`` in a file called ``mydata.json`` and then say ``--record file://mydata.json``. Does that work?