# AWS Firehose - Where is the definition of the event format to process in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

[Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Data Transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) does not provide any information about the event data format coming to a lambda function from Firehose.

How could we code a lambda function to do the transformation without such information?

Comment: They have lambda blueprints. So this can be useful for starting with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much spending time:

- [serverless-app-examples/python/kinesis-firehose-process-record-python](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-app-examples/blob/master/python/kinesis-firehose-process-record-python/lambda_function.py)
- [Build a Modern Application on AWS - Module 5](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-modern-application-workshop/tree/python/module-5)
- [Firehose API reference - PutRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html)
- [Firehose API reference - Record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_Record.html)

[image]

To get the event coming to Lambda from Firehose.

- [Generating Sample Event Payloads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-generate-event.html)

```
$ sam local generate-event kinesis kinesis-firehose
{
  "invocationId": "invocationIdExample",
  "deliveryStreamArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "records": [
    {
      "recordId": "49546986683135544286507457936321625675700192471156785154",
      "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1495072949453,
      "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IDEyMy4="
    }
  ]
}
```

---

## Testing Firehose/lambda

Testing [Build a Modern Application on AWS - Module 5](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-modern-application-workshop/tree/python/module-5) firehose and lambda with CLI.

### Testing lambda

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name ${FUNCTION_NAME} \
--qualifier ${FUNCTION_ALIAS} \
--payload file://./event.json \
response.json
```

- event.json

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "recordId": "1",
      "data": "'eyJ1c2VySWQiOiAiY3VycmVudFVzZXJJZCIsICJteXNmaXRJZCI6ICI0ZTUzOTIwYy01MDVhLTRhOTAtYTY5NC1iOTMwMDc5MWYwYWUifQ=='"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Result**
Lambda log.

```
START RequestId: e15a50f9-20a5-48ce-9942-9681291910fe Version: 13
{'records': [{'recordId': '1', 'data': "'eyJ1c2VySWQiOiAiY3VycmVudFVzZXJJZCIsICJteXNmaXRJZCI6ICI0ZTUzOTIwYy01MDVhLTRhOTAtYTY5NC1iOTMwMDc5MWYwYWUifQ=='"}]}
Processing record: 1
{
    "userId": "currentUserId",
    "mysfitId": "4e53920c-505a-4a90-a694-b9300791f0ae",
    "goodevil": "Evil",
    "lawchaos": "Lawful",
    "species": "Chimera"
}
Successfully processed 1 records.
```

### Testing firehose+lambda

```
echo "Testing Firehose put-record using --record file://./data.json"
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name ${DELIVERY_STREAM_NAME} \
--record file://./data.json

echo "Testing put-record using  --record='{"Data": "{\"userId\": \"2\",\"mysfitId\": \"2b473002-36f8-4b87-954e-9a377e0ccbec\"}"}'"
# aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name mystream --record="{\"Data\":\"1\"}"
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name "${DELIVERY_STREAM_NAME}" \
--record='{"Data": "{\"userId\": \"2\",\"mysfitId\": \"2b473002-36f8-4b87-954e-9a377e0ccbec\"}"}'

echo "Testing Firehose put-record using --cli-input-json"
aws firehose put-record \
--cli-input-json '
{
    "DeliveryStreamName": '\"${DELIVERY_STREAM_NAME}\"',
    "Record": {
        "Data": "{\"userId\": \"2\",\"mysfitId\": \"2b473002-36f8-4b87-954e-9a377e0ccbec\"}"
    }
}'
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "Data":"{\"userId\": \"2\",\"mysfitId\": \"2b473002-36f8-4b87-954e-9a377e0ccbec\"}"
}
```

#### Result

```
START RequestId: 94007e93-31d8-4da5-8231-c7cafa0d363a Version: 13
{'invocationId': '6bd3e736-2ad8-41d4-9485-a0aad1806990', 'deliveryStreamArn': 'arn:aws:firehose:us-east-2:200506027189:deliverystream/masa-ecs_monolith-firehose-extended-s3-firehose-click-stream', 'region': 'us-east-2', 'records': [{'recordId': '49605256299907973028537486643826326105740520545077690370000000', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1584590301809, 'data': 'eyJ1c2VySWQiOiAiMiIsIm15c2ZpdElkIjogIjJiNDczMDAyLTM2ZjgtNGI4Ny05NTRlLTlhMzc3ZTBjY2JlYyJ9'}, {'recordId': '49605256299907973028537486643827535031560135311691350018000000', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1584590303745, 'data': 'eyJ1c2VySWQiOiAiMiIsIm15c2ZpdElkIjogIjJiNDczMDAyLTM2ZjgtNGI4Ny05NTRlLTlhMzc3ZTBjY2JlYyJ9'}, {'recordId': '49605256299907973028537486643828743957379750009585532930000000', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1584590305222, 'data': 'eyJ1c2VySWQiOiAiMiIsIm15c2ZpdElkIjogIjJiNDczMDAyLTM2ZjgtNGI4Ny05NTRlLTlhMzc3ZTBjY2JlYyJ9'}]}

Processing record: 49605256299907973028537486643826326105740520545077690370000000
{
    "userId": "2",
    "mysfitId": "2b473002-36f8-4b87-954e-9a377e0ccbec",
    "goodevil": "Neutral",
    "lawchaos": "Lawful",
    "species": "Cyclops"
}
Processing record: 49605256299907973028537486643827535031560135311691350018000000
{
    "userId": "2",
    "mysfitId": "2b473002-36f8-4b87-954e-9a377e0ccbec",
    "goodevil": "Neutral",
    "lawchaos": "Lawful",
    "species": "Cyclops"
}
Processing record: 49605256299907973028537486643828743957379750009585532930000000
{
    "userId": "2",
    "mysfitId": "2b473002-36f8-4b87-954e-9a377e0ccbec",
    "goodevil": "Neutral",
    "lawchaos": "Lawful",
    "species": "Cyclops"
}
Successfully processed 3 records.
```

---

## References

I am afraid the AWS Firehose document is so poorly written, does not serve as a technical document.

Not to spend time in vein, personally would go through the blogs and github repositories, not the AWS Firehose document.

- [Amazon Kinesis Firehose Data Transformation with AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/)
- [serverless-app-examples/python](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-app-examples/tree/master/python) or [AWS Serverless Application Repository](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications)
- [CLI to put data into AWS Firehose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006303/cli-to-put-data-into-aws-firehose)

I do hope AWS will improve the document seriously so that we do not have to search around github, blogs, experimenting a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example lambda for python 3.7. The transformation adds `|` between Firehose records.

```
      import base64

      import json

      def lambda_handler(event, context):

          output = []

          print(json.dumps(event))

          for record in event['records']:

              print(record['recordId'])

              payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])    

              output_record = {
                  'recordId': record['recordId'],
                  'result': 'Ok',
                  'data': base64.b64encode(payload + b'|').decode("utf-8")
              }

              output.append(output_record)

          return {'records': output}
```

And the example of the firehouse `event` (partial output, as full is way to long to post:

```
{   "invocationId":"81087760-69e0-4e50-a12e-4fb46d05678a",
   "sourceKinesisStreamArn":"arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:850577719404:stream/a02e-kinesis-stream-MyKinesisStream-6JYA08YTEN6L",
   "deliveryStreamArn":"arn:aws:firehose:us-east-1:850577719404:deliverystream/a02f-firehose-MyFirehose-XHPEHGN8H2RX",
   "region":"us-east-1",
   "records":[      {         "recordId":"49605230427854536169624763988300178155600757073314316306000000",
         "approximateArrivalTimestamp":1584514759230,
         "data":"eyJtZXNzYWdlX2lkIjoxOTcsIm1zZ19ubyI6MjQxLCJhc2ciOiJhMDZlLUFTRy1jb25zdW1lcjEtTXlMYXVjaFRlbXBsYXRlU3RhY2stOTZHRVpZRTU0MkdFIn0=",
         "kinesisRecordMetadata":{
            "sequenceNumber":"49605230427854536169624763988300178155600757073314316306",
            "subsequenceNumber":0,
            "partitionKey":"fadff67a-6803-4db5-8bed-4fcbcb0ed5db",
            "shardId":"shardId-000000000001",
            "approximateArrivalTimestamp":1584514759230

}

},
      {         "recordId":"49605230427854536169624763988301387081420371702489022482000000",
         "approximateArrivalTimestamp":1584514759230,
         "data":"eyJtZXNzYWdlX2lkIjoxOTcsIm1zZ19ubyI6MjQyLCJhc2ciOiJhMDZlLUFTRy1jb25zdW1lcjEtTXlMYXVjaFRlbXBsYXRlU3RhY2stOTZHRVpZRTU0MkdFIn0=",
         "kinesisRecordMetadata":{
            "sequenceNumber":"49605230427854536169624763988301387081420371702489022482",
            "subsequenceNumber":0,
            "partitionKey":"ca681b9d-476e-4bf0-a193-9d67ac7df51b",
            "shardId":"shardId-000000000001",
            "approximateArrivalTimestamp":1584514759230

}

},
      {         "recordId":"49605230427854536169624763988302596007239986331663728658000000",
         "approximateArrivalTimestamp":1584514759230,
         "data":"eyJtZXNzYWdlX2lkIjoxOTcsIm1zZ19ubyI6MjQ1LCJhc2ciOiJhMDZlLUFTRy1jb25zdW1lcjEtTXlMYXVjaFRlbXBsYXRlU3RhY2stOTZHRVpZRTU0MkdFIn0=",
         "kinesisRecordMetadata":{
            "sequenceNumber":"49605230427854536169624763988302596007239986331663728658",
            "subsequenceNumber":0,
            "partitionKey":"ef73dafa-43b1-4b4f-bd57-e3fe56077c96",
            "shardId":"shardId-000000000001",
            "approximateArrivalTimestamp":1584514759230

}

},
```